# Migration done in WP, but now getting '300 Multiple Choices' error

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, migration, wordpress-theming, multiple-choice

I have just done a migration from a subdomain to root but now when I try to link to others pages from my site, I receive the following message:

> Multiple Choices
>
> The document name you requested (/maquetacion.php) could not be found on this server. However, we found documents with names similar to the one you requested.
>   Available documents:
>
> /maquetacion.html?page_id=56 (common basename)
>   Please consider informing the owner of the referring page about the broken link.

My index is showed fine and it is along with others pages in the following url:

> wp-content/themes/website/index.php

I have already changed my WordPress URL and site URL to be the same.

The links from my index are like this:

```
<a href="maquetacion.php?page_id=56"></a>
```

From my subdomain, the site runs rightly. Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try resetting your custom permalinks back to the default setting via Settings -> Permalinks. If this works, then review Using_Permalinks before setting a custom permalink structure back up again.

Comment: @QualityExpert I have already tried to reset the permalinks but the problem persists. The CMS works fine in my subdomain but when I copy the whole wordpress folder to the root the links break. Any change in the data base?

Comment: Did you replaced all sub domain URL to main domain URL in database?

Comment: @QualityExpert Problem solved. My root had the same pages than theme but with .html static format as well as the index and for some reason did not perform well redirection. Then I had to delete it and refresh the page and voila. Anyway, thanks a lot for all.